# Regex: finding some before and after specific word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find to find anything with an included word. So far I've got `(r'>(.*(word)?)</a>'` but I'm having some trouble. What I want is to have `some text (word) some text`.

Comment: Please give a few examples (input and expected output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```
re.findall('(.+)\(word\)(.+)','some text (word) some text')
```

gives:

```
[('some text ', ' some text')]
```

An example:

```
#1
>>> text = 'wow! python (word) is amazing!' #case with "word" in parenthesis. 
>>> re.findall('(.+)\(word\)(.+)',text)
[('wow! python ', ' is amazing!')]
#2
>>> text = 'wow! python the is amazing!'  #case without "word" in parenthesis. 
>>> re.findall('(.+)the(.+)',text)
[('wow! python ', ' is amazing!')]
```

If you use:

```
re.findall(...)[0]
```

it directly gives:

```
('some text ', ' some text')
     ↑               ↑
   prefix          suffix
```